# Material UI: Class names in development are uglified

Tags: reactjs, debugging, material-ui, development-environment, jss

I have a material ui setup with SSR. I works fine...

My problem is that when I compile my code, material-ui generates some weird classnames like `jss116` or `jss19`.

This is really annoying when inspecting my code in development. I want to have (In my development environment), more meaningful class names. Is this possible?

**server.tsx**

```
import * as path from 'path';
import * as express from "express";
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import {StaticRouter} from "react-router";
import {matchPath} from "react-router-dom";
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";
import { createStore, Action } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import {SheetsRegistry, create} from 'jss';
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider';
import {MuiThemeProvider, jssPreset, createGenerateClassName} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import App from "../shared/App";
import routes from '../shared/routes';
import theme from '../shared/MainTheme';


const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static("build/public"));

console.log("Public path:", path.join(__dirname, "public"));

const appReducer = (prevState: any, action: Action) => ({...prevState, message: "Reducer"});

app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {

    const now = new Date();
    console.log(`GET ${now} - ${req.originalUrl}`);

    const activeRoute = routes.find(route => !!matchPath(req.url, route)) || {
     path: "/" };
    // TODO: Fetch initial state according to the active route.
    const preloadedState = {activeRoute};
    const store = createStore(appReducer, preloadedState as any);

    const sheetsRegistry = new SheetsRegistry();
    const sheetsManager = new Map();
    const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName();
    const jss = create(jssPreset());



    const context = {}
    const content = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
        <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
            <JssProvider jss={jss} registry={sheetsRegistry} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
                <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme} sheetsManager={sheetsManager}>
                    <Provider store={store}>
                        <App/>
                    </Provider>
                </MuiThemeProvider>
            </JssProvider>
        </StaticRouter>
    );

    const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
    const css = sheetsRegistry.toString();

    const html = `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">            
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">            
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
            <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
            <style id="jss-server-side">${css}</style>            
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="root" style="overflow-x: hidden; width: 100%; margin: 0;">${content}</div>
            <script src="client_bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(preloadedState).replace(/</g, '\\u003c')}
            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
    `;

    res.send(html);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App is running on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

**client.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Router} from "react-router-dom";

import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {appReducer} from '../shared/reducers';

import App from "../shared/App";
import {create} from "jss";
import {createGenerateClassName, MuiThemeProvider, jssPreset} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import theme from '../shared/MainTheme';
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider';
import configureStore from '../shared/store/index';

declare global {
    interface Window {
        __PRELOADED_STATE__ : any
    }
}

const preloadedState = window.__PRELOADED_STATE__;
delete window.__PRELOADED_STATE__;
// const store = createStore(appReducer, preloadedState);
// const store = configureStore(appReducer, preloadedState);
const store = configureStore(preloadedState);

const Main = () => {
    React
        .useEffect(function didMount() {
            const jssStyles = document.getElementById('jss-server-side');
            if (jssStyles && jssStyles.parentNode) {
                jssStyles
                    .parentNode
                    .removeChild(jssStyles);
            }
        }, []);

    return <App/>
}

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName();
const jss = create(jssPreset());

ReactDOM.hydrate(
    <JssProvider jss={jss} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Main/>
            </Provider>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
</JssProvider>, document.querySelector('#root'),);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally sorted this out by running webpack like this:

`webpack --mode=development ./server.ts`

Turns out, for some reason, webpack doesn't listen to `NODE_ENV`

Comment: Where exactly do you run this ? I didn't know we have to run webpack separately when running our react app.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, you saved the day, I had exactly the same problem different webpack mode for client and server

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get meaningful names in development by properly setting NODE_ENV in your build tool.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `generateClassName` props value to your custom generator based on the environment. In production, you can just use the usual [createGenerateClassName](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#creategenerateclassname-options-class-name-generator).

For example:

```
let generateClassName = null;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  // use the default class name creator from mui
  generateClassName = createGenerateClassName();
} else {
  // make your own name generator
  const createGenerateId = () => {
    let counter = 0;
    return (rule, sheet) => `pizza--${rule.key}-${counter++}`;
  };
  generateClassName = createGenerateId();
}

// ... in render
<JssProvider generateClassName={generateClassName} ...>
  ...
</JssProvider>
```

This example was taken from [CSS-in-JS Docs](https://cssinjs.org/jss-api?v=v10.0.0-alpha.11#generate-your-class-names).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and fixed it by using the `createGenerateClassName` function and setting the `disableGlobal` option to `true`.

```
const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
    disableGlobal: true,
});

const App = () => ({
    <StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>...</StylesProvider>
});
```